# NioFileLocker bug?

Tags: spring-integration, file-locking

It appears to me that there is a bug in NioFileLocker.unlock() method (spring integration v4.1.4.RELEASE). Method clears up classloader level cache by calling `FileChannelCache.closeChannelFor(fileToUnlock);`, but it never tries to clean up its local `lockCache`.

Is this a bug, or I'm missing something? Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I've not looked at that code before, but it looks suspicious to me; please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Please also consider [contributing a fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).